# Pokemon Go crashes on open?

Tags: pokemon-go

I downloaded Pokémon Go and opened the app. It says:

> Sign up using Google.

I clicked on it and it showed me my email and then it said that Pokemon Go has stopped. This happens every time.

I've tried redownloading it 5 times but with no change. What should I do?

Comment: Pokémon Go is currently suffering from high volumes of traffic. Entire countries are attempting to log in at the same time, so it is to be expected that the servers are experiencing issues at the current time. Give it a while, and it should sort it out

Comment: The servers have been finicky all day, so you may want to try again after a little while. I've received your error a few times due to timeouts

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure its with the update of your phone because all my friends and I have the same update and it crashs just as you said. Well thats my opinion anyway

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me since the release of Pokémon Go. All I did was change the Time Zone. That should allow you to log in into Pokémon Go. I use the Britsh zone

Answer (score 0):

I used my iPad to log in and accept the terms and conditions. Then I closed off on my iPad and got on with my iPhone 4s. Worked like a charm.